# Flutter: Wrapping PageViews without size constraints in ListViews?

Tags: listview, dart, nested, flutter

**Is:**

In the code below, the example with the `GridView` on the top level works, but not with the `ListView`.

**Wanted:**

What I am trying to realize is a `scrollable page` that has a number of `Containers` in it and then a `PageView` at the end that has two `GridViews` in it.

All of the `Widgets` in this scenario are supposed to shrink to their content / children, which is also why I can't use `GridView` at the top level. This is most important for the `PageView -> GridView` structure.

**Questions:**

Why does the `ListView` example not work and the `GridView` one does?
How could I realize the wanted scenario described above?

Thank you for your attention.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage() /* MyHomePage2() */,
      );
    }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: GridView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 1,
          ),
          children: [
            GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                return Text("I am a text in a GridView in a GridView.");
              },
            ),
            PageView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                  ),
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                    return Text("I am text in a GridView in a PageView in a GridView.");
                  },
                );
              },
              itemCount: 2,
            )
          ]
        )
      );
    }
}

class MyHomePage2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                return Text("I am a text in a GridView in a ListView.");
              },
            ),
            PageView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                  ),
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                    return Text("I am text in a GridView in a PageView in a ListView.");
                  },
                );
              },
              itemCount: 2,
            )
          ]
        )
      );
    }
}
```